# Calculating input power of ACDC power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, power-electronics, ac-dc

I'm trying to calculate the input power draw of an ACDC power supply that we are using in a control chassis and am confused by what to me looks like conflicting information in the datasheet.

The power supply is an [HDR-30-24](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/hdr-30-24/7703799) with datasheet [here](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/HDR-30/HDR-30-spec.pdf). I'm confused because I see two ways to calculate the input power to this power supply (assuming drawing the full rated output power for this example).

Method 1:
The power supply has an output power rated at 36 W. The input efficiency (Typ.) is listed as 89%. So 36 / 0.89 = 40 W of input power I would expect if the load is drawing the full 36 W rated output.

Method 2:
The datasheet also says that the input AC current (Typ.) is 0.88A at 115VAC. The 115VAC is rms, so I would expect the input power to be 0.88*115 = 101 W from this calculation.

Which one is correct? What am I misunderstanding here? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Does it really say typical for the AC current?

Comment: Until someone comes along with a proper answer this might be relevant: the power rating of the unit is only 30 W so it doesn't need to meet a minimum [power factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor) value in the EU.

Comment: Yes it does actually say typical (more specifically it says "typ") for the input AC current. Also I didn't realize at 30 W it might not need to meet a minimum power factor in the EU but that could be why the real and apparent power are so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HDR-30-24](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-ultra-slim-din-rail-power-supply-input-range-hdr--30--24) is the manufacturers web page.

It has a link to the [test report](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HDR-30/HDR-30-24-rpt.pdf) shows the input current (typical) from the specification as well as the measured input current (which is less than the specification value) for the maximum output load:

[image]

The [datasheet](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HDR-30/HDR-30-spec.pdf) shows a `RECTIFIERS & FILTER` block on the input, but doesn't list a *power factor*. The *power factor* of the assumed combination of rectifiers and smoothing capacitor may explain why the result of:

- 0.54 A * 125 VAC = 67.5 W input power
- is greater than the 36 W output power / 90.9% efficiency = 39.6 W